# Wave animation from the bones

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, constraints, drivers

I have a chain of bones (20 pieces). I need to make a wave on these bones (like in stadiums) Maybe someone knows how this can be done - so that one controller can make a wave or take it away?

I would be grateful for any information.

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful to extend your Q by more details about your goal ... probably bones are not needed for desired result at all ...

Comment: The bones are used to animate the watch bracelet. And I don't know how I can make a wave on the bones, so that you don't have to animate each bone separately. I want to make one controller, which would create a wave when moving (turning)

Answer (score 1):

Something can be done with parenting bone to vertex group.
Like that you can control bones by Mesh object with assigned **Wave modifier**.

[image]

[image]

For this purpose I created a mesh strip, used add-on *Convert to Armature*, addon automatically generates a rig for the strip - Addon creates all vertex groups and bone per each face. Addon also assigns armature to the strip. That is not what we need, so delete Armature modifier.

First bone uses *Bone Constraint* > **Child of** ... other bones use *Bone Constraint* > **Copy Rotation** with specific Vertex Group.

Wave modifier generates a bit of stretch here, but constraints use only rotation parametr so your watch bracelet stay correct.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I guess the modifiers used will help me! I will try the same way to make a wave, but with the ability to use ik and fk chains

Comment: If Answer solved your issue consider mark as accepted to let others know it is solved from main list, otherwise system will poke the Q again ... or write your own Answer here and mark as accepted. Thank you keep this site organised https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Ok, I need to connect the wave with the chains ik and fk. And I will write about the result. Thank you